# phpDoc a multi-property

Tags: php, oop, phpdoc

This is quite simple.  I just want a more compact way to define phpDoc blocks for class properties when I define more than one variable at at a time, currently I have to define each separately.  For example, this is my current method of phpDoc'ing -- one by one, each visibility decleration can only define one at time:

```
/** @var int */
public $x;

/** @var int */
public $y;

/** @var int */
public $z;

/** @var Dance */
public $foo;
```

When it seems like it would be a lot easier if I could group them.  I was expecting something like this to be valid, but it does not seem to be:

```
public
    /** @var int */
    $x,
    /** @var int */
    $y,
    /** @var int */
    $z,
    /** @var Dance */
    $foo;
```

I've tried quite a few variations, including instead trying this, which also does not work:

```
/**
 * @var int
 * @var int
 * @var int
 * @var Dance
 */  

public $x, $y, $z, $foo;
```

This is pretty trivial, however I've always wondered is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, phpDoc is just a comments. So, comments cannot be invalid for PHP.

But phpDoc could be valid or invalid for tools (IDE or document generator). If you follows this standard [@var](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html) your tool would "understand"(probably) you. Also, tools could extend this standard, check documentation.

Examples

```
class Foo
{
  /** @var string|null Should contain a description */
  protected $description = null;
}
```

> Even compound statements may be documented:

```
class Foo
{
  /**
   * @var string $name        Should contain a description
   * @var string $description Should contain a description
   */
  protected $name, $description;
}
```